# How to pause and resume android game?

Tags: java, android, resume

I am making an android game called Connect4. I am facing a problem relating to pausing and resuming the game. When i run the game on a real device(on a Galaxy S2), while running the game, when i press the power button, the screen gets locked, and when i unlock the screen, my game does not resume from where i left it. Basically, i need 3 things to resume my game, a byte array, a byte, and a FrameLayout object. Here is the code I am using:-

```
......
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
    out.putParcelable("save", new Save());
}
public class Save implements Parcelable {

byte discs1, disc1[][];
FrameLayout root1;

Save(byte discs, byte[][] disc, FrameLayout root){
    discs1=discs;
    disc1=disc;
    root1=root;

}
```

Then in the onCreate() i restore them using the supplied bundle, but this not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). You'll need to overwrite `onPause()`, `onResume()` etc. with code to save and restore your game when your app loses focus.

Comment: To expand on fredley's answer, `onPause()` and `onResume()` are the two functions you're looking for. They're called when the user exits the activity (minimizing, another activity comes up) and when the user goes back to the activity, respectively. Please be aware that, in case the device runs out of memory, the Android sub-system may terminate your application so I'd suggest you save any relevant information to persistant storage (sqlite database perhaps).

Comment: but when i tested it on my phone, i found out that when i lock the screen and unlock it, onCreate() is also called. what code should i add to resume my game?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onRestart()` function.